# Does this unique_ptr own an object or a pointer to an object?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have code similar to the following:

```
CCell* pGroupCell = new CCell(
    this, RowNumber, s_NameColIndex, RowNumber,
    s_LastColIndex, NULL, RowState.GetName(), RowBehavior::Expanded, nullptr /* top-level group: no parent*/,
    _T(""), CCell::AlignLeft);

// Wrap the cells pointer in unique_ptrs for use by AddCellToGrid().  
std::unique_ptr<CCell>apGroupCell(pGroupCell);

if (!apGroupCell)
{
    return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
}

if (FAILED(AddCellToGrid(apGroupCell)))
    return E_FAIL;
```

The intent of this method is to pass the unique_ptr to the AddCellToGrid() method, which takes ownership of it.  After the call to AddCellToGrid(), the unique_ptr is empty.  Supposedly, the unique_ptr would delete the object when ownership is released.

But I'm not sure if that's what's really happening.  The CCell object is being created on the heap, with a pointer to it being used to create the unique_ptr.  But the unique_ptr is templatized on CCell, not on CCell*.  So, I'm not sure if the unique_ptr really owns the object, or if it merely owns a pointer to the object.

Comment: The pointer owns the memory.  It handles deallocating that, and in turn that deallocation process handles destroying the object in that memory.

Comment: A `unique_ptr<CCell>` holds a pointer to a `CCell`. When the `unique_ptr` gets destroyed it will delete the object that the pointer points at.

Comment: @ROBERT RICHARDSON Who owns the pointer owns the object pointed to by the pointer.:) In other words, whoever owns the wallet owns the property stored in the wallet..:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow "*whoever owns the wallet owns the property stored in the wallet*" - that is a terrible analogy. If I dropped my wallet and someone picked it up (or, if I just handed it to them), they don't automatically gain ownership of my house just because the wallet holds an ID with my house's address on it.